# Random audio coming from Safari in macOS 10.14.6

Tags: safari, audio, macos

- macOS 10.14.6
- Safari Version 12.1.2 (14607.3.9)
- Scarlett 2i2 Audio Interface

Something weird has started happening in the last 3 days. I seem to be getting random bursts of audio produced by Safari. The reason I'm blaming Safari is that one time when I managed to get to the keyboard in time, the noise ceased as soon as I quit Safari. On none of the occasions are any of the active tabs indicating any audio activity visually.

The noises in question range from non-verbal vocalisations to what sounds like reruns of audio clips that I may have played in the last few days.

I've done a full scan using Malwarebytes but that didn't find anything. I also had the idea of compressing the Safari app, deleting it and then seeing if I could re-install it from AppStore. I don't know if you've ever tried deleting Safari, but it's not so easy!

I'm about to install the Safari Technology Preview version to see if that fixes things, but it would be nice if someone could suggest a reason for this phenomenon that doesn't involve my sanity

Comment: did you check your extensions ?

Comment: I went through them in the course of setting up Safari Technology Preview. Nothing seemed wrong, as far as I could see.